# SSRS 2005 Divide values of two text boxes

Tags: reporting-services

I thought this would be simple, but i must be missing something

here is my expression

`=Sum(ReportItems!ID.Value)/Sum(ReportItems!NumberofUnits.Value)`

I get this error.

`The Value expression for the textbox 'textbox14' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.`

I really just want to divide those two report item values.

Comment: are they any aggregated values of any dataset?

Comment: @BhupeshC yes and these values are actually on a row group header

Comment: Is it possible to reference them like `sum(Fields!FieldName1.Value,"Dataset1")/sum(Fields!FieldName2.Value,"Dataset2")`

Comment: @BhupeshC Nope no shot - need to do aggregate of an aggregate and divide to get percent

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an aggregate function (SUM) on a ReportItem. remember that a ReportItem is a textbox or other object inside the report. So either change your expression to:

```
ReportItems!ID.Value/ReportItems!NumberofUnits.Value
```

Or in case your ID and NumberofUnits reportitems are inside the context of a dataset (for example, in a tablix), and both of them corresponds to fields in the dataset, do this:

```
Sum(Fields!ID.Value)/Sum(Fields!NumberofUnits.Value)
```

You may optionally specify the scope over which the SUM function should work, by adding the name of the scope (for example dataset name, tablix name, group name) as a 2nd argument to the SUM function.

Comment: Dan - do you have an example of using a group name?

Comment: Certainly. If your group is named "Group1", then simply write this: `Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "Group1")/Sum(Fields!NumberofUnits.Value, "Group1")`